# Telerik's RadAjaxManager: all user controls are refreshed

Tags: ajax, user-controls, telerik, postback, radajaxmanager

I'm using Telerik's RadAjaxManager to update panels independently.

On my page, I have 3 user controls: A, B, C.

My AjaxSettings are:

- If postback on A, update only A.
- If postback on B, update only B.
- I declare nothing for C.

If I do a postback on A, I see the loading panel on A, but (using Chrome dev tool) I see data sent for A and B. Strange to me as only A has loading panel visible when I perform action.

If I do as postback on B, same behavior: loading panel on B but data for A and B.

Now, if I remove from AjaxSettings the settings for B, when I do a postback on A, only data for A are sent.

Am I wrong, or I should only see data for the "target" panel defined in AjaxSettings?

Moreover, sometimes in our user controls we access the RadAjaxManager to add response script. Can it be related? For instance, if in B's code-behind I add script to RadAjaxManager, will the entire B content will be sent when I do a postback on A (with rule A updates A only)?

This is really an issue in our app.

Comment: Might want to check with Telerik directly, but I believe the RadAjaxManager carries the whole page in it's scope. So it's not really doing a partial postback - rather the whole page, each time and only refreshing what's 'different' based on the AjaxSettings elements. We had a similar issue updating > 1 grid and ended up doing some backend magic to reduce the amount of data being sent, as well as disabling ViewState for those controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try using RadAjaxPanel around your user controls, or you can also use RadAjaxManagerProxy on user control page that will do post back of your control itself.

Comment: Thanks, that was that. All over the app we use Asp:Panel and it works fine, but not here.